# How to handle using a authnticated Proxy in Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, https, proxy, proxies

I read alot about using HTTPS Proxies in Selenium and came to the decision to use SeleniumWire, SeleniumWire is really slow tho. Now im looking for a Method to use HTTPS Proxies in Selenium.

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for a recent Chrome:

```
import base64
auth = base64.b64encode(b'user:pass').decode()

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders", {"headers": {"Proxy-Authorization": "Basic " + auth}})
```

Let us know if it works for you.